matchImagesFeatures in appium doesn't work
I'm trying to use the matchImageFeatures method in my Appium framework, but I can't get it to work properly. Please find my configuration below, and if anyone can help me resolve this problem, I would greatly appreciate it.
config :

Appium client version : 9.3.0
Appium server version : 2.12.1
images plugin version : images@3.0.21
jdk version           : jdk-21.0.5.11-openj9

here is my code :
public boolean isImagePresent(String baseImagePath, String secondImagePath) {
        try {
             // Load the base image as a byte array
            byte[] baseImage = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(baseImagePath));
            byte[] secondImage = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(secondImagePath));

            // Generate diff image path automatically based on baseline image path
            String diffImagePath = baseImagePath.replace(".png", "_present_diff.png");

            // Perform feature-based image comparison
            FeaturesMatchingResult result = driver.matchImagesFeatures(
                baseImage , 
                secondImage,
                new FeaturesMatchingOptions()
                .withDetectorName(FeatureDetector.ORB)    // Use SIFT detector
                .withGoodMatchesFactor(40)             // Adjust match threshold
                .withMatchFunc(MatchingFunction.BRUTE_FORCE_HAMMING)  // Matching function
                .withEnabledVisualization()                // Enable visualization
            );

            System.out.println("result : " + result);
            
            // Assertions
            if (result.getCount() > 0) {
                Files.write(Paths.get(diffImagePath), result.getVisualization());
                System.out.println("Visualization saved at: " + diffImagePath);
                System.out.println("Match found! Good matches: " + result.getCount());
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("No match found.");
                return false;
            }
            
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false; // Return false if an exception occurs
        }
    }

here is what I got in the Console :
result : io.appium.java_client.imagecomparison.FeaturesMatchingResult@87dfcecc
No match found.

I'm expecting to got the visualization like below :
Visualization Exemple
I have already used other methods like "findImageOccurrence" and "getImagesSimilarity", and they work properly, but the method "matchImagesFeatures" doesn't work for me.
I specifically want to use "matchImagesFeatures" because it is more flexible and can handle scaling and rotation of images

the issue where in param of the method matchImagesFeatures , I should parse File type or a byte[] type . if using byte[] the parrsed parameter should be base64image.
here is my new code which work properly now :
public boolean isImagePresent1(String baseImagePath, String secondImagePath, int factor) throws IOException {
    // Load the original/second image file
    File originalImg = new File(baseImagePath);
    File secondImage = new File(secondImagePath);
 // Generate diff image path automatically based on baseline image path
    String diffImagePath = baseImagePath.replace(".png", "_diff.png");

    // Perform image feature matching
    FeaturesMatchingResult result = driver.matchImagesFeatures(secondImage, originalImg,
            new FeaturesMatchingOptions()
                    .withDetectorName(FeatureDetector.BRISK)
                    .withGoodMatchesFactor(factor)
                    .withMatchFunc(MatchingFunction.BRUTE_FORCE_SL2)
                    .withEnabledVisualization());

    // Perform assertions using non-deprecated assertThat
    MatcherAssert.assertThat("No visualization data was found", result.getVisualization().length, greaterThan(0));
    MatcherAssert.assertThat("No matches were found between the images", result.getCount(), greaterThan(0));
    MatcherAssert.assertThat("Total matches count is invalid", result.getTotalCount(), greaterThan(0));
    assertFalse("No points found in the first image", result.getPoints1().isEmpty());
    assertNotNull("Rectangle in the first image is null", result.getRect1());
    assertFalse("No points found in the second image", result.getPoints2().isEmpty());
    assertNotNull("Rectangle in the second image is null", result.getRect2());

    System.out.println("Image matching completed successfully!");        
    
 // Assertions
    if (result.getCount() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Count = " + result.getCount());
        System.out.println("Total Count = " + + result.getTotalCount());
        
        Files.write(Paths.get(diffImagePath), Base64.getDecoder().decode(result.getVisualization()));
        System.out.println("Visualization saved at: " + diffImagePath);
        System.out.println("Match found! Good matches: " + result.getCount());
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("No match found.");
        return false;
    }
    
    
}

